# Unable to input text in TextField in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've been trying to enter text in the TextField in SwiftUI and I've been getting stuck. There aren't any errors being flagged so I don't know if it's a bug in Xcode or just my code. I've been able to do it in the past but today it's been a bit of a challenge trying to input some text after recently updating Xcode to the latest version 13.2. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @State private var name: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("Yo \(name)"),
                    label: {
                        Text("Next")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                        
                    })
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works well for me using macos 12.2 Beta, Xcode 13.2, 
targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. Tested on real devices. I can type in the `TextField` and see the results in the destination.

Comment: Oh for real? That's cool. Yeah I haven't tested it on a real apple device yet. I wanted to see how I could it would work on Xcode cuz I thought you could enter text on there but I guess not. But thanks for letting me know it works.

Comment: It is working fine on the iOS simulator as well. Xcode 13.2.1. Remember you don't get a keyboard in previews, and on the simulator, you may have your hardware keyboard connected, so you won't get the on screen one.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the tip. I'll keep that in mind.